# Infer Nullity not working after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android-studio, androidx

After migrating to **AndroidX** through the **Refactor** menu in Android Studio, though the project compiles and works correctly, the menu tool **Analyze\Infer Nullity** doesn’t work anymore as expected. It doesn’t recognize any of the already set annotations in code.

Cleaning/rebuilding the app, and invalidating the cache, isn’t solving the issue.

Is there a setting that needed to be set after the migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Deleting the **.idea** folder within the project (while it is closed) solves the issue. When the project gets opened again the folder gets automatically recreated and the issue disappears.

I would recommend to perform a full backup of the project before trying this solution.